# `UIPanGestureRecognizer` not accessible to users who are using VoiceOver in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, uipangesturerecognizer, voiceover

The below code adds a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the whole view on screen. When a user pans across the screen with one finger the panning/swiping action is recognised and `recognizePanGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer)` is triggered.

Unfortunately though my `UIPanGestureRecognizer` code is currently not accessibility compliant.

---

**Questions:**

How can I change the code below to ensure that it is completely accessible to users who are using VoiceOver in iOS?

What is the special gesture action a user typically uses when panning with VoiceOver active?

---

**Code:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        panGestureAdd()
    }

    func panGestureAdd() {
        let panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.recognizePanGesture(_:)))
        panGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
        panGesture.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    }

    func recognizePanGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        print("UIPanGestureRecognizer active.")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VoiceOver users can perform a pan by prefixing it with the "pass-through" gesture (one-finger double-tap and hold before continuing with the gesture). You may want to offer an alternative method to access the control. One approach might be to add and conform to the `UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable` trait.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!